# Alexa Skills use slotValue as array name

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

```
if (slotValues.listableThings.ERstatus === 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
  switch (slotValues.listableThings.resolved) {
    case 'CLASSES':
      {
        lookupArray = sessionAttributes.CLASSES;
      };
      break;
   case 'TONES':
      {
         lookupArray = sessionAttributes.TONES;
      };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
```

Is there a way to do this instead of using a switch to just set lookupArray = sessionAttributes.(slotValues.listableThings.resolved)

everything I can find on javascript says to use alert but alert is not defined in node.js for alexa skills.

Comment: I want to be able to use the value in slotValues.listableThings.resolved to get the array that I want use use from sessionAttributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate thought the elements and use the key to assign

```js
// Emulating 
var slotValues = {
  listableThings: {
    resolved: "CLASSES"
  }
};

var sessionAttributes = {
  CLASSES: "THESE ARE CLASSES",
  TONES: "THESE ARE TONES"
}

let lookupArray = sessionAttributes[slotValues.listableThings.resolved];

console.log(lookupArray);
```

Comment: So I did some playing.  I could just set the array with the slotValues in bracket where you have key.  However I think the reason that failed was because I was not making sure it was a valid option first which this does.  Also it let's me set a flag for later use.  Thanks.

Comment: @JimDziak there is no need to use a for loop. You can simply assign like this: `lookupArray = sessionAttributes[slotValues.listableThings.resolved];`

Comment: @adiga I think I had tried that before and got an error if sessionAttributes[slotVlaues.listableThings.resolved] did not exist.  This method solves that problem as well.